# How to properly update Angular from version 10 to 11?

Tags: angular

I was trying to update my angular app. While updating from 10 to 11, first I run

```
1. ng update @angular/core@11 @angular/cli@11
```

Now ng --version shows this:

```
Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1102.14
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1102.14
@angular-devkit/core            10.0.4
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.2.14
@angular/cdk                    7.3.7
@ngtools/webpack                10.0.4
@schematics/angular             11.2.14
@schematics/update              0.1102.14
rxjs                            6.6.3
typescript                      4.1.5
```

Now in the second step while I was trying to run

```
2. ng update
```

It showed this list:

```
 We analyzed your package.json, there are some packages to update:
    
      Name                               Version                  Command to update
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      @angular/cdk                       7.3.7 -> 12.2.8          ng update @angular/cdk
      @angular/cli                       11.2.14 -> 12.2.8        ng update @angular/cli
      @angular/core                      11.2.14 -> 12.2.8        ng update @angular/core
```

This list makes me a bit confused. As My goal is to update 11 only. In that case, do I need to update cdk, cli and core to version 12.2.8?

Isn't updating the CDK to 11.2.14 sufficient?

what would be the correct process? Can someone please explain

Answer (score 1):

That would be enough in most cases. Just upgrade them to v11.

But, the best thing you can do is follow the official update documentation. You wont find a mistake there. Only thing to take care of is the version and dependency mismatches